# C# Linq Nullable INT Field contain within List<int> SQL translation

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I have a table with a list of forms that need signing off by managers what I am trying to do is filter the list of forms down to just the forms they can sign off.

I get a list of staff they manager then put that into a list of staff Ids.

```
var staffIds = manager.Staff.Select(x => x.Id).ToList();
```

I then filter the list of forms using the list of staff.

I get all the forms where it matches the authenticated organisation Id then remove any forms that have been rejected already then check to see if the form matches one of the following -

The form has not been "first signed off" and the staff who submitted the form is managed by the authenticated staff member.

or

The form has been "first signed off" and not "second signed off" and the authenticated staff member managers the staff member who did the first sign off.

```
var forms = (from item in DbContext.Forms
            where item.OrganisationId == authenticatedOrganisationId
                  && item.RejectStaffId == null
                  && (( item.FirstSignOffStaffId == null && staffIds.Contains(item.StaffId))
                     || (item.FirstSignOffStaffId != null
                         && item.SecondSignOffStaffId == null
                         && staffIds.Contains(item.FirstSignOffStaffId.Value)))
                             select item).ToList();
```

The issue is the SQL that is being run is incorrect. What I would expect the SQL to look like -

```
SELECT *
FROM [Forms]
WHERE [OrganisationId] = 1
    AND [RejectStaffId] IS NULL
    AND (([FirstSignOffStaffId] IS NULL
        AND [StaffId] IN (1,2,3,4))
        OR ([FirstSignOffStaffId] IS NOT NULL
        AND [SecondSignOffStaffId] IS NULL
        AND [FirstSignOffStaffId] IN (1,2,3,4)))
```

But instead it runs

```
SELECT *
FROM [Forms] AS [item]
WHERE ([item].[OrganisationId] = 1) 
    AND [item].[RejectStaffId] IS NULL
```

So then does the rest in memory, this means all the forms (which over time will become a very large data set) are returned.

What I have found is that it breaks when I add

```
staffIds.Contains(item.FirstSignOffStaffId.Value)
```

The field "FirstSignOffStaffId" is a nullable INT this seems to break the SQL being sent as with the "StaffId" field its fine but this is a INT field.

Does anyone know how to make it run correctly with a nullable INT field?

Comment: What ORM are you using? Typically if a method were not supported, it would throw an error at run time, rather than truncating the query (especially since it doesn't truncate it at that point of the query. Out of curiosity, what happens if you construct your list as `List<int?>` instead?

Comment: EF core 1.1 - I did try making it a List<int?> and it did the same thing

Comment: Even when removing `.Value`?

Comment: Ye and even tried (as i am checking if its not null already) staffIds.Contains((int)item.FirstSignOffStaffId) but does the same thing :/

Comment: It seems in EF core contains executed locally, refer similar about GUID we are discussing here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7922

Comment: Ye that looks to be the same issue, ill follow it and see what the EF team say. For now ill just do it in SQL I think :/ Thanks Anil :)

Comment: Thanks, updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With EF Core this seems to be behavior of `Contains` to execute locally for `List <int?>` , refer this [issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/issues/7922) for `List <GUID?>`

Answer (score 6):

Make staffIds a List of nullables (to avoid type cast in the query expression). Like this:

```
var staffIds = manager.Staff.Select(x => (int?)x.Id).ToList();
```

That's why IQueryable is a bad example of abstraction: you still must know alot about underlying provider...